# Type of a generic method parameter

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Let's say I have a method with a generic parameter:

```
public <U> void genericMethod(U param) {
    // doStuff
}
```

I also have two classes, one of which extends the other:

```
public class A {}
public class B extends A {}
```

And I do this:

```
A var = new B();
genericMethod(var);
```

In `genericMethod`, what is the type of `U`?

The variable I passed `genericMethod` is declared as `A`, but is actually `B`, so is `U` of type `A` or `B`?

I've tried testing it but I can't find a way to get information on `U` at runtime.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "what is the type". `var` is a reference to an object of type B.

Comment: “but I can't find a way to get information on U at runtime", because there _isn't_ any info on U at runtime. Generics are purely a compile time thing. Now knowing that, you should know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's modify your example a little:

```
public class Example {
    static class A {
        int x;
    }
    static class B extends A {}

    static <U> U genericMethod(U param) {
        int i = param.x; // compile time error
        System.out.println(param.getClass()); // prints B
        return param;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        A var1 = new B();
        A var2 = genericMethod(var1);
        B var3 = genericMethod(var1); // compile time error
    }
}
```

From the point of view of your invocation of `genericMethod`, U is of type A, so we can assign the return value to A, but not to B.

From the point of view of the implementation of `genericMethod`, U is of type `Object`, because we haven't put any bounds on it, so we can't, for instance, refer to a member field of A. If we wrote `static <U extends A> U genericMethod(U param)` then the type of U would be A.

The actual runtime type of `param` is B, as you can see if you call `getClass()`

Comment: I think this answer could make a better job of explaining the difference between 1) the compile time type of the reference variable 2) the runtime type of the reference variable 3) the runtime type of the argument object.

Comment: *"From the point of view of the implementation of genericMethod, U is of type Object"* This refers the the runtime type of the parameter variable, but without saying that explicitly. During *compile* time, the type of the parameter is simply `U` inside `genericMethod`. This can be observed clearly because you can not, for example, assign a value of type `Object` to `param`.

Comment: Also, it is not suitable to use the name `var` for variables in Java! `var` has a special meaning in Java 10 and later! The code is still legal but pretty confusing!

Answer (score 2):

Generic types are resolved in compiler time. Therefore, `<U>` is determined by the compile-time type of `var`, which is `A`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

`U` is of type `Object`, because you can pass *anything* to genericMethod.
It could be a String, an Integer, an A or a B or anything else. The most common denominator of all objects is `Object`, so inside genericMethod the type of param will be Object.

---

If you need `U` to be an A or B, it could be defined as

```
public <U extends A> void genericMethod(U param) {
```

But again the only guarantee is it is (at least) an A and so you can access properties and methods of A, but not B (though B can override properties of A).